# how to set background image dynamically for dynamically created button using tag?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I have created a  row of numberButtons inside a view dynamically.I am getting button highlighted when clicking any number.If I am clicking more than 1 in that row ,all of the clicked buttons get highlighted.What to do for avoiding multiple highlation?

I have used the code as follows

```
-(void)pressed:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    if(!button.selected){

        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(highlightButton:) userInfo:button repeats:NO];        

    } else {
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(unhighlightButton:) userInfo:button repeats:NO];
    }
-(void)highlightButton:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[sender userInfo];
    button.highlighted = YES;
    button.selected = YES;
}
-(void)unhighlightButton:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[sender userInfo];
    button.highlighted = NO;
    button.selected = NO;
}
```

Comment: How are you "highlighting" the buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you mean that every button you tap is highlighted without removing the previous highlight.

To only have one button highlighted at a time. Keep track of what button was highlighted and remove its highlight when tapping another button.

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)button {
    if (button != [self lastSelectedButton]) { // don't re-highlight the same button
        // remove the highlight of "lastSelectedButton"

        [self setLastSelectedButton:button];
        // add the highlight to "lastSelectedButton" (not updated to the new button)
    }

    // Do the rest of you button logic here ...
}
```

Comment: You need a property to store the lastSelectedButton: `@property (non atomic, weak) UIButton * lastSelectedButton;` and synthesize it: `@synthesize lastSelectedButton = _lastSelectedButton;` to be able to set and retrieve the last selected button

Answer (score 0):

Override your select method by calling deselect method in the end.
So, when you click your control will be selected and deselected instantly.